# Phoenix framework router.ex config for JSON

Tags: phoenix-framework, elixir

I've installed phoenix JSON package through `mix phoenix.gen.json V1.Post posts title:string content:string secret:string --no-model`
but got this error:

```
== Compilation error on file web/controllers/v1/post_controller.ex ==
** (CompileError) web/controllers/v1/post_controller.ex:14: Shopper.V1.Post.__struct__/0 is undefined, cannot expand struct Shopper.V1.Post
(elixir) src/elixir_map.erl:55: :elixir_map.translate_struct/4
(stdlib) lists.erl:1353: :lists.mapfoldl/3
(elixir) src/elixir_clauses.erl:36: :elixir_clauses.clause/7
(elixir) src/elixir_def.erl:178: :elixir_def.translate_clause/7
(elixir) src/elixir_def.erl:167: :elixir_def.translate_definition/8
(elixir) src/elixir_def.erl:82: :elixir_def.store_definition/9
web/controllers/v1/post_controller.ex:13: (module)
(stdlib) erl_eval.erl:669: :erl_eval.do_apply/6
```

here is my router.ex code:

```
defmodule Shopper.Router do
use Shopper.Web, :router

pipeline :api do
    plug :accepts, ["json"]
end

scope "/", Shopper do
    pipe_through :api
    resources "/v1/posts", V1.PostController
end
end
```

From the documentation said:

> Add the resource to the proper scope in web/router.ex:
>
> > resources "/posts", PostController

But.. I can't make it work, could anybody help me? Thank you.

Please note that this is for phoenix 1.0 and elixir 1.0.

Comment: I'm also very new to this elixir + phoenix ecosystem, so please bear with me

Comment: It was supposed to just work. Which commands did you pass to "mix phoenix.gen.json"? Have you changed anything afterwards? In any case, the error seems to be you are calling "Shopper.V1.Post" on line 13 of your controller and you likely have a model defined "Shopper.Post" instead.

Comment: @JoséValim I've added the full command in the question and I didn't change anything. Just trying to run it, then got this error. Thanks

Comment: @JoséValim Hmm.. I think it's a bug in the "phoenix.gen.json" since I defined for no-model, but it still needs a model (repo)?

Comment: Maybe it is a documentation bug. It will always need a model, the data needs to come from somewhere. `--no-model` is useful when the model already exists and you just want to re-use it.

Comment: It's not mentioned anywhere.. I guess. I think I'll add my own answer after successfully add the model.

Comment: Yes, it is a docs issue. I will improve it on master.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My question is pointing to wrong problem, but I'll keep it that way so it can help people who coming with similar conclusion.

The solution is to add a model for V1.Post but running `mix phoenix.gen.model` will give a compile error which already stated in my question. So, I must comment the offending code which is the entire `def create(conn, %{"post" => post_params})` in V1.Post controller.

After that run `mix phoenix.gen.model V1.Post posts name:string` then uncomment the offending code.

To test, run `mix phoenix.routes` which in my case returning

```
Compiled web/models/v1/post.ex
Generated shopper app
page_path  GET     /                  Shopper.PageController :index
post_path  GET     /api/v1/posts      Shopper.V1.PostController :index
post_path  GET     /api/v1/posts/:id  Shopper.V1.PostController :show
post_path  POST    /api/v1/posts      Shopper.V1.PostController :create
post_path  PATCH   /api/v1/posts/:id  Shopper.V1.PostController :update
           PUT     /api/v1/posts/:id  Shopper.V1.PostController :update
post_path  DELETE  /api/v1/posts/:id  Shopper.V1.PostController :delete
```

Success!